# Finding html string index using plan string start index and end end index

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an html text string and also start index and end index of its text form (without HTML). Like -

```
var htmlstr = "<b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <i>dolor</i> in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <span>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt</span> mollit anim id est laborum."
var startindex = 0; // can be change
var endindex = 123; // can be change

/* Text form (0 to 123) without html tag
   "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
*/
```

Can anybody suggests how we can find the same index for htmlstr?

Expected result:-

inside htmlstring that index will be 130.

```
/*
   "<b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
*/
```

Comment: Please check the answer and accept it. Or, leave a comment for rejection.

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Thanks, Now I understand; How I can solve or approach on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
let span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = htmlstr;

setTimeout(function() {  // wait for `span` to be rendered
    let target = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    let [i, j] = [0, 0];
    for (let child of span.childNodes) {
        let rest = target.substring(j);
        if (rest.startsWith(child.textContent)) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                i += child.textContent.length;
            else
                i += child.outerHTML.length;
            j += child.textContent.length;
        } else if (child.textContent.startsWith(rest)) {
            i += rest.length;
            if (child.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE)
                i += child.outerHTML.indexOf('>') + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(i);
}, 1000);
```

`htmlstr` will be rendered as DOM element. Then you have both `outerHTML` and `textContent` for each element.

For each step, we can decide which one of child node and the rest of `target` `startsWith` the other. If `textContent` of achild node `startsWith` the rest of the `target` text, it is done.

So, if `target` text `startsWith` `textContent` of a child node, index will increase by the length of `outerHTML` or the length of `textContent`.

Exceptionally, if `target` text ends inside non-`TEXT_NODE` element, index will increase by the length of `textContent` plus the length of an opening tag.